# What Is the major benefits Of Pranayam?

Tags: yoga

[Pranayama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pranayama) is a [Nitya-karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitya_karma) daily activity ([Kumbhaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbhaka) pranayam is used in [Sandhyavandana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhyavandanam)) and is major part of yoga and Hinduism. What are benefits of pranayama both medicinal and spiritual aspects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of benefits of *Pranayama*.It is a part of **Astangik Yoga** and is beneficial for the both medicinal and spiritual aspects.It is divided into three parts :-

---

**Puraka**---------------------------*Puraka means to inhale.*

**Kumbhaka**-------------------------*Kumbhaka means to retain the* breath.

**Rechaka**------------------------- *Rechaka means to exhale.*

---

#### Sprituals Benefits of Pranayama

According to **Panchsikhacharya** :

> ***TAPO NA PARAM  PRANAYAMAT TATO VISHUDHI MALANAAM DIPTISHCH GYANASYA ||***
>
> There is no other  tenacity greater than Pranayama, the scum of mind is erased by it and then light of knowledge becomes visible.

The Pranayama clears the scum of mind and body same as we use fire to clear the scum of metals like gold.

Another benefit of Pranayama is stability of mind and ability to continue further in **Astangik Yoga**.

#### Medicinal  Benefits of Pranayama

- Reduces the frequency of breath or breathing rate.It reduces breathing rate from 15th breaths a minute to 6-7 breaths a minute.
- Slow down heart rate
- Reduced wear and  tear of internal organs
- Help lowering the blood-pressure
- Reduces the effects of old-age problem like headaches,stiffening muscles and joints and various others.

[Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/kmu/kmu08.htm) is the power of pranayama yoga:

> Pranayama is the best method for suffering humanity to overcome diseases, conquer fear, overcome nervousness or despondency. It opens the door of Blessed Peace, it gives hope to the hopeless, power to the poor, faith to the faithless. There is no other way to control the mind, as mind is nothing without desire or thought; desires and thoughts are nothing without Prana.